# NTFS on the mac - worth paying for?

Tags: macos, mac, ntfs

I currently use ntfs-3g on my mac to be able to write to NTFS-formatted drives. I have seen two commercial alternatives that boast better performance and more advanced features -  [Tuxera](http://www.tuxera.com/products/tuxera-ntfs-for-mac/) (a commercial version of ntfs-3g it seems) and [Paragon](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-mac/).

Are these products really better? Any experiences, hard facts, benchmarks from real-world use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bought Tuxera and have been using it for a while now. I have noticed a few improvements:

- Faster read and write. I haven't made a benhcmark but it's noticeable, I used to reflect on how slow a NTFS drive was when connected to the mac, I don't have that reflection anymore.
- Handles drives that have been "yanked" without unmounting them first. With NTFS-3G I would often have to use a windows computer to handle this.
- Not a single stability issue despite pretty intense usage, local windows partitions and external drives being juggled about pretty frequently.

So the answer to my original question is "yes", it is worth paying for.

Answer (score 1):

NTFS-3G community edition is free. I use it with Macfuse

http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-download/

http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/

Comment: I'm confused, the ask-er said "I currently use ntfs-3g on my mac..."

How is this an answer?

Comment: Oops ! The asker edited his question...?

Comment: no he didn't...?